# Error while uploading a file from the c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload

I am uploading an Excel sheet from the code. When I am trying it from local system, it's working fine but after deploying the website into IIS, when I am trying to upload the file the following error is thrown:

> Upload Error : Cannot access a closed file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retry with a small text file. If that works, it might be because of the limit of the file size set on the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://www.aspspider.com/qa/Question1999.aspx) and [here](http://sanjaysainitech.blogspot.com/2008/12/file-upload-error-can-not-access-closed.html) this kind of error is often caused by the filesize being too large.  Try posting a file with a smaller size to confirm the solution works, then a larger file to reproduce the problem.  Also, the second link contains a possible solution.